# ASP.NET gRPC: how to import other proto file?

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc

I have a VS 2019 ASP.NET gRPC Server project.
It has 2 proto files in the same folder:

```
Protos\mainsvc.proto
Protos\enums.proto
```

The enums.proto contains a declaration some of common enums which I'd like to use in multiple
proto files.
How can I import his enum.proto file to the mainsvc.proto?
Now I have:

```
syntax = "proto3";
option csharp_namespace = "MyGrpcService";
package MyServer;
import "enums.proto"; // <- error: cannot find the file.
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto"; // <- its OK
```

Comment: your code has a typo (enums vs enum)

Answer (score 2):

The paths to your imported proto files must be expressed as a relative path to the project (.csproj) file. In you example this means you should have (assuming the .csproj file is located in the parent directory to `Protos`):

```
import "Protos/enums.proto";
```

I believe this is specific to the ASP.NET gRPC tooling.